# Ordered list numbers disappear using jQuery SlideDown

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown, slideup

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb7aP/)

Can anyone explain why:

a. The numbers in the ordered list do not appear until the animation is complete. Causing it to jerk when the numbers pop in.

b. After closing the accordion for the first time, the numbers do not return.

When toggling the header, the css for the .sublinks switches once from Visible to Hidden, then never changes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** EDIT ***

I fixed it! Check out this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QtQjx/

*** END EDIT ***

You have conflicting padding for your `.sublinks` class in your CSS.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.sublinks {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:10px 0 20px 55px;
}

.sublinks {
    padding:0;
}
```

On the one hand you're telling it to give the `.sublinks` list `padding:10px 0 20px 55px` and on
the other hand you're telling it to give it no padding at all. Get rid of the second `.sublinks` and
change the padding of your first `.sublinks` to 10px 0px 20px 0px.

Also, inspecting the drop down when the numbers have disappeared, I noticed that it updates top-level 
OL code to the following:

```
<ol class="loweralpha sublinks" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; height: 335px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 20px; ">
```

If you can find out how that is happening and eliminate the `overflow:hidden`, I think you'll solve
your problem.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't know how to solve the jerking issue - you will have to address that based on the rest of your code. However, I do have a very simple fix for your ordered symbols disappearing:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function() { 
     $(".sublinks").slideToggle(500, function() {
         ...perform your style changes that you were doing on callback here...
     }); 
});
```

The other thing that I can suggest to you is that you try using fade effects instead of slide effects. You can make a very smooth fade effect that will "slide" your list in and fade each element one at a time and it will look much cleaner than the slide will. Also, your elements shouldn't jump so much. The slide effects are very jumpy in nearly every browser. The fade effects are supported by all browsers (though IE doesn't support fadeTo). If you decide to use fades instead and need help writing the plugin let me know and I'll be happy to help you.

Good Luck :)